# Nested Select in Eloquent

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I want to recreate below SQL in Eloquent (Laravel 6 LTS)

I want to avoid DB::raw as I have logics behind the PartnerPrice::class (model)

```sql
SELECT *
    FROM (SELECT *,
                 ROW_NUMBER ()
                 OVER (PARTITION BY group, TYPE
                       ORDER BY effective_at DESC, created_at DESC)
                    r
            FROM partner_prices
           WHERE     group = 'premier'
                and partner_id = 8
                 AND TYPE = 'premium'
                 AND effective_at <= '2020-10-31') a
   WHERE r = 1
ORDER BY group;
```

Here's my working inner query.
I just need help wrapping this with another select and add a where('r', 1)

```
$sub = PartnerPrice::select('*')
        ->selectRaw('ROW_NUMBER () OVER (PARTITION BY mccmnc, TYPE ORDER BY effective_at DESC, created_at DESC) r')
        ->where('type', $type)
        ->where('partner_id', $partnerId)
        ->where('group', $group)
        ->where('effective_at', '<=', now()->subMonth()->lastOfMonth())
        ->get();
```

Comment: You need to search for subqueries, look at https://laravel-news.com/eloquent-subquery-enhancements for example

Comment: But my outer select is not any Model. Perhaps I can wrap DB::table($sub) some how?

Comment: I see, indeed. In that case there is no real point to start with the PartnerPrice as the main select. You might be able to use it as subqueries though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `toSql` method with `mergeBindings` like this

```
$queryBuilder = PartnerPrice::select('*')
        ->selectRaw('ROW_NUMBER () OVER (PARTITION BY mccmnc, TYPE ORDER BY effective_at DESC, created_at DESC) r')
        ->where('type', $type)
        ->where('partner_id', $partnerId)
        ->where('group', $group)
        ->where('effective_at', '<=', now()->subMonth()->lastOfMonth());

$result = DB::table(DB::raw('(' . $queryBuilder->toSql() . ') as a'))
    ->mergeBindings($queryBuilder->getQuery())
    ->where('a.r', 1)
    ->get();
```

Note that I omitted the `get()` on the first builder

Also I think you can use

```
DB::select('*')
    ->fromSub($queryBuilder, 'a')
    ->where('a.r', 1)
    ->get();
```

But never used it. try this too.

Comment: Well thats all I know :) May be some one will answer better. It got me curious too. Lets see

Comment: However, i plan to use this as Scope in my Model. Is it possible?

Comment: I may have found the answer. See the update, Let me know if it works.

Comment: @zaiman you should be able to use it as a scope too, you just have to return the builder instance as far as i know

Comment: DB::fromSub returned error `Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\MySqlConnection::fromSub()`

Comment: Oh thats is bad. What about adding the select(‘*’) before fromSub? I dont’t have my PC to test it out. I just discovered the method in the API doc. https://laravel.com/api/7.x/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.html#method_fromSub

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224900/discussion-between-zaiman-noris-and-mohamed-mufeed).